# working in visual studio 2010 on windows xp

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-xp

I was working on my source files on windows 7. For some reasons I need to work on my source file in windows xp. I doubt if all the batch files will work or not? Will there be any problem if i change the platform from Windows 7 to XP? Please suggest.

Comment: This question is vague and difficult to answer.  Do you have any areas of specific concern?

Comment: why question is vague? If i use visual studio 2010 on xp means it will miss anything or working good? this is my question.I already working the file on windows 7 only. Now i change that file to xp means any error occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio 2010 without problem on Windows XP (with SP3), since it is an officially supported OS (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=133421).

Of course, Windows has developed a lot since XP was released. Take for example improvements in technologies such as WPF, the IDE will work somewhat faster and more stable on the newer operating systems; however this won't prevent you from using it on XP.

If you are referring to batch files you wrote yourself, you should ensure that all functions are suported under XP and work as expected, since some tools have been have been added or changed in Windows 7 (for some examples see [here](http://www.tomcarpenter.net/2010/03/19/windows-7-batch-files-more-of-the-same/)).